# Sync from Google Cloud Postgres DB to Amazon Aurora RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql, psql

I want to periodically sync my Cloud SQL Postgres DB with an Amazon Aurora DB.

Setting up a Lambda that does `pgdump` and `psql` from one to the other should work but is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Do you want to replicate the data from amazon aurora rds to Cloud SQL postgres?

Comment: other way around

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Database Migration Service in AWS. As long as one of the databases is in AWS (which Aurora is) you can use it to perform full-loads + continuous migration using Change Data Capture. PostgreSQL is supported, so you'd have to create a migration instance, configure the Postgres and Aurora endpoints and set up a replication task.

**Reference**

- [Creating tasks for ongoing replication using AWS DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Task.CDC.html)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up running a pg_dump and psql cron job on an EC2 instance. I could not access GCP db as endpoint as from DMS for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only solution for now, You're not alone, there is a [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/120090073) on this particular matter, in case you were wondering.